# Why am I getting invalid command name ".!canvas"? I couldn't find a working solution anywhere

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a project that automates your virtual school schedule by automatically joining your meetings on time and alerting you about them. What I am trying to have right now is a working tkinter setup window in which you can add links to a dictionary variable. All I want is for a window that asks the user to enter a link and a number and for the user to be able to click a "Finish" button that will destroy the window. I got the code down, hopefully, but I keep getting "in _create
return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"". I've done a good amount of research and I can't find a solution. Note: I've already tried win.update() and moving the win.mainloop() to the bottom.

```
# Import Webbrowser
import webbrowser as wb

# Import Tkinter
import tkinter as tk

# Set Up Tkinter Window
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Setup")
win.resizable(False, False)

# Set Up Tkinter Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width=400, height=300)
canvas.pack()

# Set Up Tkinter Big Header
header = tk.Label(win, text="Auto School Meetings Setup")
header.config(font=("helvetica", 14))
canvas.create_window(200, 25, window=header)

# Set Up Tkinter Entry
instructions = tk.Label(win, text="Enter a link and time here for every class you have")
instructions.config(font=("helvetica", 10))
canvas.create_window(200, 100, window=instructions)

linkEntry = tk.Entry(win)
canvas.create_window(200, 140, window=linkEntry)

timeEntry = tk.Entry(win)
canvas.create_window(200, 180, window=timeEntry)

# Create Link Dictionary From Input
finished = False
links = {}


def addLink(t, newLink):
    links[t] = newLink

link = linkEntry.get()
time = timeEntry.get()
addBtn = tk.Button(
    text="Add Link",
    command=addLink(time, link),
    bg="blue",
    fg="white",
    font=("helvetica", 9, "bold"),
)
canvas.create_window(100, 220, window=addBtn)
quitBtn = tk.Button(
    text="Finish Setup",
    command=win.destroy(),
    bg="green",
    fg="white",
    font=("helvetica", 9, "bold"),
)
canvas.create_window(300, 220, window=quitBtn)
win.update()
win.mainloop()

# Test Links
wb.open(links.get("1", "www.google.com"))
```

Heres the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Osprey\Desktop\School Meetings\main.py", line 58, in <module>
    canvas.create_window(300, 220, window=quitBtn)
  File "C:\Users\Osprey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2809, in create_window
    return self._create('window', args, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Osprey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2771, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Comment: The `command` option to `tk.Button` should be a function reference, not the result of calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Remove the parentheses after `win.destroy()`. It should be `win.destroy`.

You're not using the `command` option to the `Tk.Button` function correctly. The argument needs to be a function reference, so that the function can be called when the button is clicked. You're calling the function when you create the button, instead of passing a reference.

If you want to pass parameters, use a lambda, as I've shown below in `addBtn`.

If there are no parameters, just pass the function name, without putting `()` after it.

```
addBtn = tk.Button(
    text="Add Link",
    command=lambda: addLink(time, link),
    bg="blue",
    fg="white",
    font=("helvetica", 9, "bold"),
)
canvas.create_window(100, 220, window=addBtn)
quitBtn = tk.Button(
    text="Finish Setup",
    command=win.destroy,
    bg="green",
    fg="white",
    font=("helvetica", 9, "bold"),
)
```

Comment: Okay so the window now appears, but my addLink function won't run. Ive placed print statements in it and none of them printed. Ive used the lambda way you showed here and the partial() from functools, yet the code in addLink does not run. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: No, I can't think of a reason for that.

Comment: @Osprey Take a look at my answer below to understand why thats happening